# Type inference for imperative statements other than assignment

Tags: types, computer-science, language-design, type-inference, side-effects

In my search for research papers about type systems for imperative languages, I only find solutions for a language with mutable references but without genuine imperative control structures such as compound operators, loops or conditionals.

So it's not clear how an imperative language with partial type inference such as http://rust-lang.org can be implemented.

The papers don't mention parametrized types such as `List of a` because parametrized types are a trivial extension of Hindley-Milner type system - only the unification algorithm should be extended, and the rest of inference works as is. However, assignments cannot be trivially added because paradoxes arise, so special techniques such as ML value restriction must be applied.

Can you recommend any parers or books describing a type system for a language with imperative loops, conditionals, IO and compound statements?

Comment: Hi. This question might be more appropriate on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. As @GustavBertram suggests, check out cstheory.stackexchange.com. This question is better suited for that site, as StackOverflow is intended for specific questions about solving technical development problems.

Comment: I closed this as not constructive because the question (to me) is somewhat borderline, but just way too broad for Stack Overflow. Migrating this to a sister site would have been problematic, because questions that ask for open ended lists (or papers, links, etc) are generally not well received. Please don't take this personally, I found your question interesting, it's just not a good fit for SO, and unfortunately not something I could just migrate.

Comment: I'm nominating for reopening. If you're familiar with the subject matter, then this can be answered pretty straightforwardly and specifically. It's too technical for programmers, and far too low-level for cstheory. Implementing type systems is as much a part of programming as are implementing data-structures with certain performance characteristics or implementing algorithms for efficient storage and fast rendering of 3d scenes.

Comment: Just to add to that -- even though this includes a reference request, I think it can be answered directly and relatively briefly.

Comment: eh, nevermind -- it did end up getting a good rapid answer on cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8892/type-inference-for-imperative-statements-other-than-assignment